# How variables and memory works in PHP

Tags: php, memory, variable-assignment

Hello im interested in understanding how variables are stored in php.

say i have two variables

```
$p = 1 + 1
$b = $p.
```

Does php save the result of the variable or does it save the procedure to run it?
Why im wondering is if i store a function in it, does it store the return value or just copies the procedure.

Thank you!

Edit:  I think it be best if i clarified what im talking about.

say:

```
    function foo($something)
{

    for loop
        {
       echo 'Something';

       }

   return $something;
}


$b = foo(5);

echo $b;
```

from what i encountered just assigning the value executes the function. And when i echo $b it also executes the function again.

Comment: `$b` would contain 2. Just copies the value of `$p` into it.

Comment: i understand $b would contain two , but say p was a more complex function. Would it run the function again?

Comment: @Dahnny012 can you give us an example?

Comment: certainly i was in class but ill work on it right away

Comment: Nah it will literally be the values. A function that returns a value when called will return it's value into the variable. The function would only be called the once and it's return value stored. Say you do `$a = strlen("hello");` the return value of `strlen()` would be stored in `$a` and then you do `$b = $a;` the value of `$a` is copied to `$b` rather than it looking back and executing `$b = strlen("hello");`

Answer (score 0):

So what you're wondering if you're assigning like this

```
$a = function($arg){
    echo($arg);
}

$b = $a;
```

will you have a duplicate of function in memory?

Oops turns out i'm wrong. PHP uses copy-on-write mechanism, which makes both `$b` and `$a` use the same memory buffer UNLESS any of these variables are modified.

Other possibility is you're wondering what happens when you do something like

```
$a = 5; $b = 15;
$c = sin($b)*sqrt($a);
```

Then, only the value of these calculations will be stored in memory, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I did understand what question you *really* wanted to ask!

PHP (like any other language) stores values inside variables. Not more, not less. So the question is: what is a value? :-)

In the example you gave the value `(int)2` is stored in both, `$p` and `$b`.

You can store a function inside a variable and there are even more possibilities. It is more a question of how you code, not of how php stores such thing:

```
$func = create_function('$a','return sprintf("*-%s-*", $a);');
echo $func('hello'); // will return "*-hello-*"
```

You can also call a functions existing in a permanent manner via a variable:

```
function echo_a($a) { return sprintf("*-%s-*", $a); }    
$func = 'echo_a';
echo call_user_func($func, 'hello'); // will return "*-hello-*"
```